# It is possible to bind a golang channel into a template

Tags: go, go-templates

I have the go templates (`upload.tmpl.html`) like this :

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>current fileName : {{ .fileName}} </li>
    </ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

an handler `uploadHandler.go` with

```
func UploadHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    file, header, err := c.Request.FormFile("file-upload")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Erreur dans la récupération de fichier")
    }
    //...
    fileName := make(chan string)

    go ReadCsvFile(bytes, fileName)
    go func() {
        for {
            log.Info(<-fileName)
        }
    }()

    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "upload.tmpl.html", gin.H{
        "fileName":    <-fileName,
    })
}
```

and the `ReadCsvFile()` method like that :

```
func ReadCsvFile(bytesCSV []byte, fileName chan string) {
    r := bytes.NewReader(bytesCSV)
    reader := csv.NewReader(r)
    reader.Comma = ';'

    records, err := reader.ReadAll()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    db, _ := databaseApp.OpenDatabase()
    defer db.Close()
    for _, record := range records {
        fileName <- record[0]
        product := &em.Product{
            Name:        record[0],
            //...
        }
        db.Create(product)

    }
    fileName <- "done"
}
```

I try to display the current fileName of each line in the template, but it is possible to bind the channel into the template like this ? Because in this way the page does not load anymore.

Comment: after rendering  all you can do is to "refresh" the page using ajax/js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Websockets. Here are some examples:

HTML/JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var ws= new WebSocket("ws://yoursite.com");
    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log(event.data);
        // $('#your-element').html(event.data);
    }
</script>
```

Go Websockets:

```
func websocketSenderHandler(conn *websocket.Conn){
    for {
        msg := <- globalChannel
        conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, msg)
    }
}
```

More Websockets in Go: [golang.org/x/net/websocket](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket)

Other Example: https://github.com/golang-samples/websocket

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't that be `websocket.Message.Send(conn, &msg)`? I can't see a `WriteMessage()` function there, just a `Write()` which is used to be compatible with the `io.Write()` interface?

Comment: Based on this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18152) and [commit](https://github.com/golang/net/commit/97edce0b2e423f6a8debb459af47f4a3cb4ff954) using std websocket package isn't a best idea. [Gorilla websocket](github.com/gorilla/websocket) is more preferable.

Comment: @olegkovalov my example is gorilla websocket.

Comment: @dit [More Websockets in Go](golang.org/x/net/websocket) points to std package, that's why I've mentioned about deprecation